# UITableView after deleting a row, position of remaining rows

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have created a table view in iOS and implemented delete row functionality. Everything is working. I have one doubt,

Consider the following case,

Suppose the table has 15 rows, and if I delete row no 10. Sometimes the cells from the top (1-9) animate from top to bottom to the position of row no 10. Sometimes the cells from the bottom(11-15) animate to the top. This occurs in random.

This is the code for deleting

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle
forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
NSLog(@">>> Entering %s <<<", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);

if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
{
    [[self contents] removeObjectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    NSArray *indexPathsToRemove = [NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath];

    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathsToRemove     withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}

NSLog(@"<<< Leaving %s >>>", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
}
```

And between this is [tutorial](http://briterideas.blogspot.in/2012/07/uitableview-how-to-part-6-inserting.html) I am following

You can download the project from [this link.](http://briterideas.com/blog_images/tableviews/part6/BTITableViewModification.zip)

Is there anyway to control this behaviour.

Thanks in advance

Comment: post your code what you have tried.

Comment: What kind of row animation have you put?

Comment: I have updated the post with the code

Comment: I am using UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic row animation

Comment: its the automatic thats controlling behaviour. Try changing it to somthing else or UITableViewRowAnimationNone

Comment: I have tried with UITableViewRowAnimationRight but the result is the same. I don't think that controls the behaviour after row delete. That is used the specify the animation of how to delete the row. I am talking about what happens to the remaining rows, after deleting a row.

Answer (score 0):

You can control it with

```
withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic
```

There are various option available

```
UITableViewRowAnimationBottom
UITableViewRowAnimationFade
UITableViewRowAnimationRight
...
```

Actual method is:

```
    [mainTableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
```

Comment: This is the style for specifying how to delete a row. My query is what happens after deleting the row. After row deletion sometimes rows from the top come to the bottom and sometimes rows from the bottom move to the top. Is there a way to control this.

Comment: are you reloading table view ?

Comment: No I don't reload the tableview